# Testing that a file gets created within a certain amount of time in rspec

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, rspec

I have this ruby project where I spawn a process. This process creates a log file when it starts.

I'm having a hard time testing this. Currently I start the process, sleep for a short amount of time (0.1 seconds) and check if the file was created.

The rspec test looks something like this:

```
describe 'the process' do
  it 'should create a log file' do
    start_the_process
    sleep 0.1
    expect('log-file.log').to exist
  end
end
```

This works well on my machine, but this test is flaky. When it runs on CI, it  fails because the process didn't have enough time to create the file. 
I could increase the time. This would fix the problem on CI, but it would make the test slower.

What I really want to test is that the file gets created within the next 3 seconds. If I sleep for 3 seconds, the test would take way too much time to run. One approach would be to check that the file exists in a loop and fail if we don't see the file within the next 3 seconds. There doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing this with rspec.

Comment: I updated my answer and probably U could get an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you're coming at it from too high a level.  You should be testing the logging class rather than the process.  For example:

```
class Logger
  def initialize
    # create the log file
  end
end
```

Then your in your spec:

```
describe Logger do
  let(:log_file_path) { 'log-file.log' }
  let(:subject) { described_class.new }
  it 'creates a log file on new' do
    subject
    expect( log_file_path ).to exist
  end
end
```

Then you can trust that the log file is created when your process instantiates a new `Logger` object.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not the one actually creating the log file. To be specific, I start `mongod ... --logpath log-file.log` and I want to test that I give it the right log file path.

Answer (score 0):

How about this then.

```
describe 'the process' do
  let(:sleep_time) { env is CI ? 3.0 : 0.1 }
  it 'should create a log file' do
    start_the_process
    sleep sleep_time
    expect('log-file.log').to exist
  end
end
```

Comment: This should work. I don't like the idea of having the test behave differently in dev and in ci. On ci, the test is "it should create the log file within 3 seconds" while on dev it's "it should create the log file within 0.1 seconds". It's also possible that the test fails on some dev machines because they're machine is slow or overloaded.

Answer (score -2):

Normally when testing time related stuff, we stub the time to avoid problem like yours, you could do something like:

```
it "test" do
  time = Time.parse("Jan 01 2015")
  Time.stub!(:now).and_return(time)

  # your test, because now when you say 
  # Time.now, it will always returns 'Jan 01 2015'   
end
```

## Updated answer

I think you could use the same technique and override the `sleep` method in you spec and return 0, by that was, there will not be a wait.

Comment: OP wasn't asking about time-related stuff.